# RSA и электронная цифровая подпись

Tags: delphi, rsa

Доброго времени суток! Кто может указать на исходник или исчерпывающую статью по формированию алгоритма RSA и ЭЦП? Алгоритм нужен на delphi.

Comment: лучше всего, если кто-нибудь укажет на исходники. Посмотреть на реализацию охота.

Answer (score 1):

CryptoApi - это оболочка, в ней ней реализации. Вот тут есть достаточно понятная реализация длинной арифметики 
[FGint](http://www.submanifold.be/triade/GInt/gint.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft CryptoAPI](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/crypto/usingcryptoapi.xml) + [RSA](http://book.itep.ru/6/rsa_642.htm)